# Why the post method doesn't write a new object to a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, ecmascript-6

When i go  to the route '/gallery/add', I add the test object: `obj` to the method `db.write(obj)` in order to transfer this object to 'db.js' where, using the `write(data)` method, I format the incoming object into 'JSON'. Then I write it to the file: 'posts.json' and push object to the `this.formatePicture` array.

**But when going to the route, '/gallery/add'  the object is not added to the file and to array, there are no errors. Tell me what i doing wrong and how using the method post add my object to the file: 'posts.json' and to `this.formatePicture` array  when navigating through the route '/gallery/add':**

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const Database = require('./db');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const db = new Database();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/gallery', (request, response) => {
    if (request.query.id) {
        const picture = db.read(request.query.id);
        picture.then(data => {
            response.send(data);
        })
    } else {
        const pictures = db.read();
        pictures.then(data => {
            response.send(data);
        })
    }
});

app.get('/gallery/:id', (request, response) => {
    const picture = db.read(request.params.id);
    if (!picture) {
        response.status(404);
        response.send();
    } else {
        picture.then(data => {
            response.send(data);
        });
    }
});

app.post('/gallery/add', (request, response) => {
    const obj = {id: 88, title: 'test', date: 'test', url: 'test'};
    const newPicture = db.write(obj);
    newPicture.then(data => {
        response.status(200).send(data);
    })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

**db.js:**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.formatePicture = [];
    }

    read(id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile('./posts.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    this.formatePicture = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (id) {
                        const pictureID = this.formatePicture.posts.find(p => p.id == parseInt(id));
                        resolve(pictureID);
                    } else {
                        resolve(this.formatePicture);
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
    write(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const converData = JSON.stringify(data);
            fs.writeFile('./posts.json', converData, {flag: 'a'}, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(this.formatePicture.posts.push(data));
                }
            })
        })

    }
}
module.exports = Database;
```

**posts.json:**

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2018-10-22T14:10:37.578Z",
      "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
      "url": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/90/39/16/903916b9f0db6992f1a4b66ae3129fbe.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "2018-10-22T14:10:37.578Z",
      "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
      "url": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/okup/images/d/da/C683c20a5b0ae062b2325653f2fd3bdf.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170131193210&path-prefix=da"
    }
      ]
}
```

Comment: `resolve(this.formatePicture.posts.push(data));` This should be changed to this: `resolve(this.formatePicture.push(data));`. I have no idea why it is not saving to the file though

Comment: I copied your files into an application locally, ran it, and was able to write into the *posts.json* file.

I did make the mistake of making a GET request initially instead of POST, which returned no errors but did not write to the file.

You may have some other problems with the data being written, it is not the same structure as the starting file.